# Using parameters for CREATE relationship in Neo4j

Tags: parameters, neo4j, insert

How do I give `RELATIONSHIP Type` as a parameter in the following `CREATE` statement?

```
String query = "MATCH (n:User),(m:User) WHERE  n.id = {srcId} AND m.id = {dstId} CREATE (n)-[{r:{type}} {dateAdded:{dateAdded}}]->(m)";
```

This line has to be modified.

```
public static void TransactionExample() throws Exception
{
    Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver( "bolt://localhost", AuthTokens.basic( "neo4j", "admin4j" ) );
    Session session = driver.session();

    String query = "MATCH (n:User),(m:User) WHERE  n.id = {srcId} AND m.id = {dstId} CREATE (n)-[{r:{type}} {dateAdded:{dateAdded}}]->(m)";

        try ( Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction() )
        {
            tx.run(query,Values.parameters("srcId",srcId,"dstId",dstId,"relType",relType,"dateAdded",dateAdded));
            tx.success();
        }
    }
    session.close();
    driver.close();
}

org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Invalid input '{': expected whitespace, comment or ']' (line 1, column 98 (offset: 97))
"MATCH (n:User),(m:User) WHERE  n.id = {srcId} AND m.id = {dstId} CREATE (n)-[{relType:{relType}} {dateAdded:{dateAdded}}]->(m)"
```

Answer (score 3):

Relationship types are not paramterizable. You'll have to do string concatenation in order to make your query work.

Comment: This means that I'd have to write two different transaction methods. One for nodes and one for relationships. Can I do anything to this line, in order to avoid it? `tx.run(query_type,Values.parameters(propertiesArray.get(i)));`

Comment: Where do `propertiesArray` comes from ?

Comment: A JSON is mapped to an object, and then I wrote a method to return an array of key/value items for the object.

Answer (score 1):

[APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_creating_data) provides a procedure call to create a relationship between nodes with a dynamic type:

```
MATCH (n:User),(m:User) 
WHERE  n.id = $srcId AND m.id = $dstId
CALL apoc.create.relationship(n,$type,{dateAdded:$dateAdded}, m) YIELD rel
RETURN n, rel, m
```

Comment: I tried it and it did work!
here is an exemple on the offshore leaks graph (after importing csv)
              
MATCH (i1:Intermediary {node_id:e.START_ID}),(e:Edge),(i2:Intermediary {node_id:e.END_ID}) 
CALL apoc.create.relationship(i1,e.TYPE,{},i2) YIELD rel
Return i1,rel,i2

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you need:

```
MATCH (n) -[r]- ()
WHERE n.uuid = $uuid and `**type(r)**`= $relType
RETURN r
```

Comment: That works for matching. Does not work for relationship creation.